# React: Card component share same state

Tags: reactjs, use-state

Created `RenderCard` component which creates multiple cards for given data.

[image]

I am creating bulk selection of card means selecting multiple cards. So when user click on `circle` present at the top left then that circle become `check circle`

[image]

So here the issue is that all card gets selected when user click on any card. So I want only that card select which users click

```
const Card = () => {
  const [cardSelect, setCardSelect] = useState(false)
  const onMouseEnter =  () => {
    console.log("onMouseEnter1")
  }

  const onMouseLeave =  () => {
    console.log("onMouseLeave1")
  }

  const logMessage =  () => {
    setCardSelect(prevCheck => !prevCheck);
  }
  const RenderCard = () => {
    return album.map(item => {
      return (
        <Col className='container' onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave} key={item.title} md='2'>
          <Card>
            <div>
              <Link to={`/pages/blog/detail/${item.id}`}>
                <CardImg className='img-fluid image' src={item.img} alt={item.title} top />
              </Link>
            </div>
              <div className='select-card'>
              {cardSelect ? <CheckCircle onClick={logMessage} /> : <Circle onClick={logMessage}  />}
            </div>
            <CardBody>
              <CardTitle className="image2 te" >
                  <b>{item.title}</b>
              </CardTitle>
              <CardText>{item.comment} Comments</CardText>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      )
    })
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Row>
        <RenderCard />
      </Row>
    </>
  )
}
```

Anyone can point me in the right direction where I am doing mistakes.

Thanks

Comment: Please create a live example, because in your example you have multiple errors and it's hard to replicate. You can use codesanbox or something similar

Comment: Your component is recursive? It renders itself

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly i would suggest that
you should wrap anything that is inside the return statement and refactor it to its own component, and then pass item as prop in that component and make the clickhandler inside that component. like this:

```
const RenderCard = () => {
    return album.map(item => {
      return ( <Component item={item} />)
  }
```

Now the component have its own state that shows either its clicked or not clicked

Answer (score 0):

With this line of code  :
`cardSelect ? <CheckCircle onClick={logMessage} /> : <Circle onClick={logMessage}  />`

You are saying : "If `cardSelect` is `true`, then render `CheckCircle` component, otherwise, render `Circle` component and do that for **all** `items` in `album` list". So when the state changes, it will render only one type of object `CheckCircles`, or `Circles` as many times as there are elements in the `album` list for which you are calling the `map` method.

That is why you are seeing all checked circles when you set your variable `cardSelect` to `true`.